# Chat for Personally Money

Tags: discussion, chat

I've created a chat on the [chat.stackexchange.com](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) site.  On other sites we've found it useful for co-ordinating and planning how to make a better site.  I hope y'all will join me there!

["Show Me The Money" Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22/show-me-the-money)